# var/log/syslog.1 file is expanding rapidly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, diskspace

My var/log/syslog.1 has expanded to a very large size of about 500+ GB and taking up my disk space unnecessarily.
This is the log which has been piled up inside the file

```
Dec 27 16:39:45 divus org.gnome.Nautilus[4124]: [00007fbb20948c00] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

Should I delete this file or is there any other way how I can stop it from unnecessary logging. 
I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with a 1TB HDD

Answer (score 0):

I did not removed it instead

> sudo echo "" > syslog.1

It will empty your logfile content without affecting your ownership of the file

Try restarting and upgrade your video driver if it resolves.

I'm also having the same issue let me know once you find your issue resolved.